# How to take best n Docs of multiple buckets and do sub aggregation on it

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

I like to take the best n Documents per user which is stored as user_id in my index.
This wouldn't be a problem until now.
It can be done like this:

```
{
    "query":{
        "match":{
            "field":{
                "query":"query_string"
            }
        }
    },
    "aggs":{
        "group_by_user":{
            "terms":{
                "field":"user_id"
            },
            "aggs":{
                "top_n":{
                    "top_hits":{
                        "size":10
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But now I like to do a sub-aggregation on it to calculate some expensive scoring and this isn't possible anymore, because top_hits is a metric aggregation.

```
"aggs":{
    "max_score_per_user":{
        "max":{
            "script":"advanced_scoring"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I also can't user the rescore feature with the window parameter, because I first have to bucket the documents per user and then take the best n per user.

The range query would work, but the results of the tf-idf scoring aren't comparable. So I can't define a proper range.

So is this just not possible or what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can make your `max_score_per_user` a sub aggregation of `group_by_user` and the `top_n` aggregation a sub aggregation of `max_score_per_user`:

```
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "field": {
                "query": "query_string"
            }
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "group_by_user": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "user_id",
                "order": {
                    "max_score_per_user": "desc"
                }
            },
            "aggs": {
                "max_score_per_user": {
                    "max": {
                        "script": "advanced_scoring"
                    },
                    "aggs": {
                        "top_n": {
                            "top_hits": {
                                "size": 10
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That would be actually a great idea, but my scoring algorithm is expensive and there are some short queries which would calculate it on thousands of results per user instead of 10.